# Voice activated offline voice recorder

Tags: voice-command, voice-recording

Sometimes while driving or washing the dishes some idea pops up in my head while I am listening to music.

How may I record voice without touching the phone?

(Sometimes while driving in remote places I do not have Internet connection so it needs to work offline)